# How to remove my email from spam-lists/blacklists after malware issue?

Tags: malware, email, blacklist

I am not sure this is the proper place to ask this question, but I am sure someone will be able to help me :)

I have a Mac, which I use for daily working (emails, etc.). Recently, I received some weird return emails with strange content. After investigating a bit, I found out that I had some malware sending emails from my account and it even created new accounts in my domain (which is not hosted by me, but by a third-party) and also sent emails to people.

I am not sure if I started/infected the server too, but my account was being used to send spam and Avast found a few files in my computer that I had to delete. Now, everything seem like it is ok, but when I send some emails to my clients, I get them back saying this:

```
SMTP error from remote mail server after RCPT TO:<my.client.email@client.com>:
554 5.7.1 Service unavailable;
Client host [SOME.IP.ADDRESS] blocked using b.barracudacentral.org;
Client host blocked using Barracuda Reputation, see http://www.barracudanetworks.com/reputation/?r=1&ip=xx.xx.xx.xx
```

So it seems that I am in some blacklist/spamlist and some of my clients are not getting my emails. Apparently, my colleagues are not having the same problem. How can I get my email removed from those lists?

Answer (score 2):

If you are on one blacklist, you are likely to be on several now or in the next few days or weeks.  You will need to check several times.  Several services provide limited free ongoing periodic checks (more services for paid subscription).

Here are three tools you can try in addition to delisting with Barracuda itself (per answer by Nicholas Leader).  I know there are many others.  The first two provide direct delisting links or other information on how to get delisted. 
https://www.ultratools.com/tools/spamDBLookup
http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx
https://robtex.com -- RobTex site is being revamped, so for now follow the old site link, enter your ip, and look at the extensive blacklist section.

Many blacklists will delist once easily, but subsequent listing will be much harder to remove (e.g., mandatory 30 day wait since last report).  Be sure your Mac, server, etc., really are clean.  At the very least, try running several of the free scanners/tools from other (not Avast in this case) vendors on your Mac.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with checking Barracuda's reputation lookup: http://barracudacentral.org/lookups